# Can my question be improved?

Tags: discussion, support

[NPC AI articles for walking and fighting?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48789/npc-ai-articles-for-walking-and-fighting)

I'm still looking for how to implement a walking non-player character which I think is on-topic. I don't really think that the question should have been closed, or that it can be improved for reopening. I need a good algorithm for NPC AI.

Comment: It was closed as not construtive, probably it was deemed to broad.

Comment: Check out the [FAQ], there's a list of sites there that have more open policies for asking open-ended questions like the one you want answered.

Answer (score 4):

Step 1, answer the question, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

You should fully delineate what you want your AI to do to the best of your ability, solve all the problems you think you can solve, and only then come to us when you have something specific that you need help with.

As is, it doesn't seem like you have tried anything.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is asking us to be your version of Google. You want links to stuff.

That's not what Stack Exchange sites are for. If you have a specific question, then ask that specific question. Don't ask a question that's a request for links.